# Why getDerivedStateFromProps does not allow to re-render with the state update? Not a problem for componentWillReceiveProps - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm trying to move from componentWillReceiveProps to getDerivedStateFromProps and in some cases, I was successful but when the case is append the props to the existing state, then things start to not behaving the same way. When a make an update to the component's state, the state changes (and the component did after updated) but still renders the previous state. Something weird happens when using getDerivedStateFromProp instead of componentWillReceiveProps. **It seems that method does not handle well with 'internal' changes. In the following example, I have getDerivedStateFromProp on Child and it works, but because is only rendering the props. This behavior was also observed in a simpler example where I didn't have any child components and was just rendering state changes.**

The code below shows a child component that is used to print/show the data received by props while uses a delete data handler (to remove data that is stored at Parent from child component interaction). When using `getDerivedStateFromProps()` I can't access to `this.state` and the prevState doesn't mean the same since the state is accumulative. And when I remove data from the child component, doesn't update the props of the child (while using componentWillReceiveProps was OK). So, I do not find a way to substitute my `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps`

componentWillReceiveProps:

```js
  UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.setState({
      data: [...this.state.data,...nextProps.data]
    })
  }
```

getDerivedStateFromProps:

```js
   static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps,state) {

    if (!isEqual(nextProps.data, state.data)) {
      return {
        data: [...state.data, ...nextProps.data]
      };
    }
    return null;
  }
```

***The original code that works as intended (before getDerivedStateFromProps on Parent Comp.)***

DataConsole - Parent Component:

```
export class DataConsole extends Component {
  // Used for unsubscribing when our components unmount
  unsub = null;

  static defaultProps = {
    data: [],
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };

    this.handleTableRowClick = this.handleTableRowClick.bind(this);
  }


   UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.setState({
      data: [...this.state.data,...nextProps.data]
    })
  }

  handleTableRowClick(key) {
    console.log(
      "handleTable",
      key,
      this.state.data[key],
      this.state.data.length
    );
     const e = this.state.data.splice(key, 1)
     //console.log("remove?", e , this.state.data.length)

    this.setState({
      undoDataRemove: e
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Container
          fluid
          style={{ paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight: 0 }}
          className="DataContainer"
        >
          <Row noGutters>
            <Col sm={8} className="ConsoleTable">
              <div>
                <DataViewer
                  data={this.state.data}
                  rowClickHandler={this.handleTableRowClick}
                />
              </div>

       ...
```

DataViewer - Child Component

```
import isEqual from "react-fast-compare";
...

export class DataViewer extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    data: [],
  };

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={data: []}
  }


  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("DataViewer updated");
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevProps) {

    console.log(nextProps, prevProps)
    if (!isEqual(nextProps.data, prevProps.data)) {
      return {
        data: nextProps.data
      };
    }
    return null;
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className={"TableData"}>
        <Table responsive="lg" striped borderless hover>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.data.map((elem, ids) => {
              if (!isEmpty(elem)) {
                return (
                  <tr key={ids} onClick={() => this.props.rowClickHandler(ids)}>
                    <td>{ids + 1}</td>
                    {Object.keys(elem).map(function (value, idx) {
                      return (
                        <td key={idx}>
                          {value}:{elem[value]}
                        </td>
                      );
                    })}
                  </tr>
                );
              } else {
                return null;
              }
            })}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (!isEqual(nextProps.data, state.data)) {` you may missed the state.data

Comment: thank you @Sundar, I will check if it's only this typo making troubles. (UPDATE) unfortunately was only a copy-paste mistake

Comment: are you still facing the issue or its resolved

Comment: Still facing the same problem. The  missing  of `state.data` was only a copy-paste mistake from the original.

Comment: with this data i can't help you on this... need more information required about `nextProps.data` and `state.data`

Comment: Sure, I added the components code to the post. Thank you very much

Comment: You're not showing where `isEqual` comes from. I assume `lodash`, but please do clarify that and whether the data is an array or object.

Comment: `static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)` signature itself is wrong...

Comment: Hi @Slbox, it comes from `react-fast-compare`.  I update the post with this, thank you. The code that I'm showing with parent-child components works well, but the problem appears when I'm moving the parent's `componentWillReceiveProps` to  getDerivedStateFromProps, It doesn't like internal changes I guess

Comment: Can you check if you pass the `props.data` to the parent component properly? the array should be copied every time it is updated. If you pass the same reference of `data` to the component, it might not trigger the `getDerivedStateFromProps()` in the parent component.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. But you should not create redundant data (copying props into state). I tried your code in a sandbox after some refactoring and it works as expected. [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-didupdate-getderived-13nwj).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in your code that causes your problem, and it is unrelated to `getDerivedStateFromProps` and `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps`.

The faulty line is this:

```js
const e = this.state.data.splice(key, 1)
```

It changes `this.state.data` without calling `setState`. Never do that. The only way you are ever allowed to make any changes to `this.state` is via `this.setState` or by returning something to be merged into state from `getDerivedStateFromProps`, not any other way.

In order to more easily cope with changes deep in your state tree, immutable libraries come in handily. [immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/) is currently among the top candidates in this category. Using `immer`, you can modify `state` any way you want, as long as you wrap it into a `produce` call using the pattern `this.setState(produce(this.state, newState => { /* change newState here */ }))`:

```js
import produce from 'immer';

// ...

this.setState(produce(this.state, newState => {
  const e = newState.data.splice(key, 1);
  newState.undoDataRemove = e;
}));
```

Hope, this can help.

Comment: Hi @Domi, I understand your point.  I use a setState right after this `data.splice` in order to  tigger the component update and,  if I scope `componentDidUpdate()` I saw the changes. But it's related to something, because if I stick to `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps` , this does not shows as a problem.  But, thank you for your insight,  I will use and explore more the use of immutable libraries, immer seems cool!

Comment: If you do it your way, `isEqual(nextProps.data, state.data)` will be `true`, so your derived state will not work as intended. You think, it is safe, because you follow it up with a `setState` and you try to wrap it using those custom hooks, but trying to change `state` without creating a new value (cascadingly) is asking for trouble and bugs, especially when it comes to compatability. Most libraries in the React universe that are related to state will only do shallow comparisons, and not even allow you changing the comparison function.